# Ruby - How do I sort one array with another array using sort_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to sort the first array:

```
 filenames = ["z.pdf", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.rf", "a.rf","a.txt", "z.html", "a.html"]
```

by the following file's extensions array:

```
 extensions = ["html", "txt", "pdf", "rf"]
```

using `sort_by`.  But when I try:

```
 filenames.sort_by { |x| extensions.index x.split('.')[1] }
```

I get:

```
 ["a.html", "z.html", "z.txt", "a.txt", "a.pdf", "z.pdf", "z.rf", "a.rf"]
```

The filenames with extensions "txt" and "rf" are not sorted.  I've tried to figure out how `sort_by` sorts by using a tuple but haven't been able to find the source code for `sort_by`.

How can I sort one array by another array using `sort_by`?

---

Edit:

The result should look like:

```
["a.html", "z.html", "a.txt", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.pdf", "a.rf", "z.rf"]
```

Comment: "please use Ruby's built in File class for this"? You mean like my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort by the index of the extensions array, then the filename:

```
filenames = ["z.pdf", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.rf", "a.rf","a.txt", "z.html", "a.html"]
extensions = ["html", "txt", "pdf", "rf"]

p sorted = filenames.sort_by{|fn| [extensions.index(File.extname(fn)[1..-1]), fn]} #[1..-1] chops off the dot
#=> ["a.html", "z.html", "a.txt", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.pdf", "a.rf", "z.rf"]
```

Comment: The OP appears to want to sort by extension-list major, filename minor.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted = filenames.sort_by do |filename|
  extension = File.extname(filename).gsub(/^\./, '')
  [
    extensions.index(extension) || -1,
    filename,
 ]
end
p sorted
# => ["a.html", "z.html", "a.txt", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.pdf", "a.rf", "z.rf"]
```

This uses the fact that the sort order of arrays is determined by the sort order of their elements, in the order they are defined.  That means that if `sort_by` returns an array, the first element of the array is the primary sort order, the second element is the secondary sort order, and so on.  We exploit that to sort by extension major, filename minor.

If an extension is not in the list, this code puts it first by virtue of `||= -1`.  To put an unknown extension last, replace `-1` with `extensions.size`.

Comment: `File.extname`, that's it!

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
>> filenames.sort.group_by{ |s| File.extname(s)[1..-1] }.values_at(*extensions).flatten
[
    [0] "a.html",
    [1] "z.html",
    [2] "a.txt",
    [3] "z.txt",
    [4] "a.pdf",
    [5] "z.pdf",
    [6] "a.rf",
    [7] "z.rf"
]
```

[`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) comes from Enumerable, and is a nice tool in our collection toolbox, letting us group things by "like" attributes. In this case, it's grouping on the file's extension, retrieved using [`File.extname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-extname), minus its leading '.'.

It's important to understand *why* `File.extname` is important. A file can have multiple sections delimited by '.', for various reasons. Simply using `split('.')` is a recipe for disaster at that point, because code following the split will have to deal with more than two strings. Other files don't contain a delimiting '.' at all. `File.extname` makes a reasonable attempt to retrieve the *last* extension found in the name, so it is a bit more sane way of dealing with file names and extensions. From the documentation:

```
File.extname("test.rb")         #=> ".rb"
File.extname("a/b/d/test.rb")   #=> ".rb"
File.extname("foo.")            #=> ""
File.extname("test")            #=> ""
File.extname(".profile")        #=> ""
File.extname(".profile.sh")     #=> ".sh"
```

[`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) comes from Hash, and extracts the values from a hash, in the order of the keys/parameters passed in. It's great for this sort of situation because we can force the order of the values to match the order of keys. When you have a huge hash and want to cherry-pick certain values from it in one action, `values_at` is the tool to grab. If you need your "by-extensions" order to be different, change `extensions` and the output will automagically reflect that as a result of `values_at`.

Comment: This discards any file which has an extension not in the list, but if that's alright, it's very pretty and easy to understand.

Comment: Yeah, `File.extname`, that's it! I'm basically a noob anyway, I just learned it today, in the process of being here.

Comment: This is a cool answer, but it doesn't use sort_by.  Can the answer to be modified to use sort_by?

Comment: Here's my question back: why use `sort_by` when it will result in a slower execution? It's important to know *when* to use a tool and *why* to use it and there is no benefit using `sort_by` with this algorithm because it has added complexity and overhead.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the expected runtime of your algorithm vs using sort_by?

Comment: Doing a brute force cycling over both arrays would give an O(n**2) execution time.  Is sort_by faster or is your approach faster?

Comment: `sort_by` uses a Schwartzian Transform. That adds overhead when sorting simple objects like strings. It gains speed when the object has to be manipulated prior to comparing because `sort` would require that multiple times. My use of `sort` is on an array of strings to provide the preliminary ordering. `sort_by` in that situation wastes CPU. You can benchmark the various answers to determine speed. Some might be faster with a small sample and change when the sample gets big. It's all a trade off and you pick based on your expected use.

Answer (score 1):

```
filenames.sort_by{|f| f.split(".").map{|base, ext|
  [extensions.index(ext), base]
}}
```

Comment: This looks like it sorts on the filename first and then the extension giving the result - ["a.html", "a.pdf", "a.rf", "a.txt", "z.html", "z.pdf", "z.rf", "z.txt"] - which isn't what I want.

Comment: On the other hand flipping ext and base works, as in - filenames.sort_by{|f| f.split(".").map{|base, ext| [extensions.index(base), ext] }}.  Not completely sure why.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["z.pdf", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.rf", "a.rf","a.txt", "z.html", "a.html"]
extensions = ["html", "txt", "pdf", "rf"]
extensions.each_with_object([]){|k,ob| ob << filenames.find_all {|i| File.extname(i)[1..-1] == k }.sort}.flatten
#=> ["a.html", "z.html", "a.txt", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.pdf", "a.rf", "z.rf"]
```

Comment: I added Edit 1 to show what the result should look like.  I'm not asking to sort the filenames on their extensions alphabetically.  I want to sort the filenames in the order of the extensions array.

Comment: 1 - This result has the reverse sort of the filenames - ["z.html", "a.html", "z.txt", "a.txt", "z.pdf", "a.pdf", "z.rf", "a.rf"].  2 - I would like the answer to use sort_by.

Comment: The question was to use "sort_by".

Answer (score 0):

```
extensions = [".html", ".txt", ".pdf", ".rf"]
filenames.sort_by { |file_name_string|
  [ extensions.index( File.extname file_name_string ), file_name_string ]
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I got it sorting on the filename first and then the extension - ["a.html", "a.pdf", "a.rf", "a.txt", "z.html", "z.pdf", "z.rf", "z.txt"]  which isn't the result I want.

Comment: That's enormously interesting, my machine gives output `["a.html", "z.html", "a.txt", "z.txt", "a.pdf", "z.pdf", "a.rf", "z.rf"]`... To get the output you indicated, I have to swap the orded of elements in the array inside `sort_by` block body...

Comment: I'm running rails c on a Mac Pro and I still get the same answer.  I just cut and pasted your answer into the rails console.  Strange because your answer is similar the other answers that work.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use the File class. Just the light and simple regex.

```
filenames.sort_by{|i| i.scan(/\..+$/)[0]}
```

Comment: This sorts by the extension itself, not by the extension's position inside `extensions`.